# Multi-geo managed metadata, terms replicated with label + Guid

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, managed-metadata, term-store, multi-geo

We have an Office 365 tenant with 5 geolocations, Europe being the primary location.

When creating terms in the Europe termstore they are (as expected) replicated to all the satellite locations. But, the label of the terms is not correctly replicated.

Instead of replicating the terms with the same internal GUID and the label, the label gets set to `[LABEL]_[GUID]`

Example:

Source termset

```
Cars
    Volvo
    Ford
```

Satellite, replicated, termset

```
Cars
    Volvo_c746b94e-271f-459c-baad-8e2c0db68e1a
    Ford_b3cc6c0d-2760-42d3-be1f-4dae6c93fd32
```

Is this the expected behavior? It does not look to good, e.g. in user profile properties bound to term sets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We opened a support ticket against Microsoft, confirming that this was unexpected behavior. The issue was fixed bu the support.